# function returning same-ness [0, 1] of two positive numbers

Tags: functions

I am looking for a function $f(a, b)$ which has the following properties (where $m \neq n$):

- $a \in \mathbb R_{>0}$ and $b \in \mathbb R_{>0}$
- $f$ returns a real number anywhere from $0$ to $1$. *
- $f(m, m) = 1$
- $f(m, n) < 1$
- $f$ is continuous (if $m \approx n$ then $f(m, n) \approx 1$)
- $f(m, n) = f(n, m)$

An example for such a function would be $f_1(a, b) = 1 - \frac 2 \pi arctan(abs(a-b))$.
[Graph of $z = f_1(x, y)$ (x and y from 0 to 10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFOTF.png)

In my particular case I have a list of cables, each with that cable's length (typically in the range of $10^1$ to $10^{3.5}$ mm). I want to sort that list by how well the length of each cable matches a given length and I also want to have a somewhat indicative value of how close it is. If two cables have a very similar but not equal length, the function should return a high value. This should be independent of the absolute lengths. So:

- $f(m, n) \approx f(km, kn)$ (ideally $f(m, n) = f(km, kn)$) for any $k \neq 1$

This is not the case for $f_1$. $f_1(10, 9) = 0.5$ indicates that they are somewhat close, but $f_1(1000, 900) \approx 0.006$ indicates that they are **completely** different.

* (Would $f(a, b) \in[0, 1]$ be <s>the correct</s> an acceptable notation here?)

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking too hard.
$$
f_2(a, b) = \begin{cases} \frac a b \text{ for } a < b \\
\frac b a
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Is that continuous?

Comment: @GregoryGrant I'd say so, yes. It doesn't have any gaps, poles or jumps. Here's a graph: https://imgur.com/a/YpCDL The weirdness close to $x = y = 0$ is just a rendering error.

Comment: Ok a picture's worth a thousand words

Answer (score 0):

One example: $\displaystyle f(m,n)=1 - \frac{|m-n|}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}$ is a continuous function $\mathbb R_{>0} \times \mathbb R_{>0} \to (0,1]$ such that:

- $f(m,m) = 1$
- $f(m,n) = f(n,m) \lt 1$ for $m \ne n$
- $\lim_{n \to 0} f(m,n) = 0$
- $f(\lambda m, \lambda n) = f(m,n)$ for all $\lambda \gt 0$

Comment: Yes, that is another solution. The graph is very similar to that of my solution: https://imgur.com/a/DaqmW How did you come up with it, though?

Comment: @NikoO Both my example and yours are of the form $\displaystyle f(m,n) = 1 - \frac{|m-n|}{g(m,n)}$ where $g$ is a "normalization" factor no smaller than $|m-n|$ symmetric and homogeneous in $m,n\,$. My example uses $g(m,n) = \sqrt{m^2+n^2}\,$, while yours is equivalent to $g(m,n) = \max(m,n)\,$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. I'm not sure which answer to accept now. I'll use the division because it's simple, but your answer is valid too.